# How do I click a button on a worksheet to execute a macro that steps through worksheets and then returns to the worksheet with the click button?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that applies an operation to each worksheet in my workbook; this macro works. I need to place a click button on each worksheet that executes this macro and then returns to the worksheet on which the button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Store a reference to the active worksheet at the beginning of the macro (before you switch worksheets). At the end of the macro activate the reference to return to the initial worksheet.

Public Sub ClickMacro()

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet          'Store reference
Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate 'Change worksheet, do work
ws.Activate                   'Return to initial worksheet
```

End Sub

Comment: Thanks, alex957. I'm a novice at writing macros, but I swear I had tried this exact same thing; apparently I had the syntax wrong. Anyway, it worked like a charm. Thanks again.